# How to send email from php using godaddy credentials

Tags: php

I'm using the below code for sending email

```
<?php
try {
    require_once "Mail.php";
    require_once "Mail/mime.php";
    $from = "user@domain.com";
    $to = "user@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Testing";
    $message = "Hi";
    $host = "godaddyhost";
    $port = 465;
    $username = "user@domain.com";
    $password = "password";
    $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
            echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
            echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
?>
```

I'm facing the below error in my Log file

```
[Wed Dec 27 22:46:25.893118 2017] [:error] [pid 3047] [client 127.0.0.1:35984] PHP Warning:  require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/testmail.php on line 3
[Wed Dec 27 22:46:25.893195 2017] [:error] [pid 3047] [client 127.0.0.1:35984] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/testmail.php on line 3
```

I'm using `PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )` and `PEAR Version: 1.10.5`

Did I miss installing any packages?

Any other alternatives for sending email? I have to make it work in local as well as in godaddy site.

Comment: Looks like the [Pear::Mail](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail) library either isn't installed or isn't in your `include_path`

Comment: Try swift mailer https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer

Comment: have you tried PHPMailer? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer